# using mapply with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Continuing on my quest to work with functions and ggplot:

I sorted out basic ways on how to use lapply and ggplot to cycle through a list of y_columns to make some individual plots:

```
require(ggplot2)
# using lapply with ggplot

df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"), col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=c(3, 2, 1), col3=c(4, 2, 3))
cols <- colnames(df[2:4])
myplots <- vector('list', 3)

plot_function <- function(y_column, data) { 
     ggplot(data, aes_string(x="x", y=y_column, fill = "x")) +
     geom_col() + 
     labs(title=paste("lapply:", y_column))
}

myplots <- lapply(cols, plot_function, df)
myplots[[3]])
```

[image: lapply_plot_3]

I know what to bring in a second variable that I will use to select rows. In my minimal example I am skipping the selection and just reusing the same plots and dfs as before, I simply add 3 iterations. So I would like to generate the same three plots as above, but now labelled as iteration A, B, and C.

I took me a while to sort out the syntax, but I now get that mapply needs to vectors of identical length that get passed on to the function as matched pairs. So I am using `expand.grid` to generate all pairs of variable 1 and variable 2 to create a dataframe and then pass the first and second column on via `mapply`. The next problem to sort out was that I need to pass on the dataframe as list `MoreArgs =`. So it seems like everything should be good to go. I am using the same syntax for `aes_string()` as above in my `lapply` example.

However, for some reason now it is not evaluating the y_column properly, but simply taking it as a value to plot, not as an indicator to plate the values contained in `df$col1`.

HELP!

```
require(ggplot2)
# using mapply with ggplot

df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"), col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=c(3, 2, 1), col3=c(4, 2, 3))
cols <- colnames(df[2:4])
iteration <- c("Iteration A", "Iteration B", "Iteration C")

multi_plot_function <- function(y_column, iteration, data) { 
     plot <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x="x", y=y_column, fill = "x")) +
     geom_col() + 
     labs(title=paste("mapply:", y_column, "___", iteration))
}

# mapply call 
combo <- expand.grid(cols=cols, iteration=iteration)
myplots <- mapply(multi_plot_function, combo[[1]], combo[[2]], MoreArgs = list(df), SIMPLIFY = F) 
myplots[[3]]
```

[image: mapply_plot_3]

Comment: What do you mean? In your hands does the code put out a different plot for the mapply version than mine? Or is it the same as with my lapply function (i.e. showing values 4, 2, 3 for a, b, c respectively)?

Comment: Sorry, I was just looking at the code issue earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to use rowwise here

```
out <- lapply(asplit(combo, 1), function(x)
           multi_plot_function(x[1], x[2], df))
```

---

In the OP's code, the only issue is that the columns are `factor` for 'combo', so it is not parsed correctly.  If we change it to `character`, it works

```
out2 <- mapply(multi_plot_function, as.character(combo[[1]]), 
    as.character(combo[[2]]), MoreArgs = list(df), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

-testing

```
out2[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for both solutions. Great to be learning about the `asplit` option (which seems simpler than using mapply) and thanks also for catching the bug. Not understanding the exact nature of what is passed is by now my number one coding issue.

Comment: @MarioNiepel I think it is based on the `expand.grid` which for some reason by default returns `stringsAsFactors` as TRUE

Comment: Yes, it's so often my issue. Here I didn't catch it because when I checked for this issue I simply printed the values, which doesn't tell me if it is the right type. I'm becoming more and more aware of this, but it's a learning process. Just like it took an our out of my life to understand that I had to wrap the df into a list first. :D

Comment: @MarioNiepel Usually, I do `str` first before doing anything because it can give vital signs

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I need to learn that 'seeing the value' is less important than understanding the type/class.